# Can't select [type:radio] by css

Tags: css, dom

Here is my code

for some reason I can't target the radio boxes for `[type=radio]:checked`.
Therefore I can't switch the styles when I click the radio buttons.
It will work if I remove the `div` around the `input` but I need to add more divs around it.

Any help would be appreciated

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .regular {
                color:pink;
            }
#toggle-2[type=radio]:checked ~ .right-column .inner1 li.regular
{
   background: gray;
    color:white;
}
#toggle-1[type=radio]:checked ~ .right-column .inner1 li.premier
{
   background: red;
   color: lightgray;
}
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div>
    <input type="radio" id="toggle-1" name="radio">
<input type="radio" id="toggle-2" name="radio">
            </div>
<div>I'm controlled by toggle. No JavaScript!</div>
                    <div class="right-column">
                        <div class="inner1">
                            <div class="pink">this is a test</div>
                            <ul>
                              <li class="regular_m">a</li>
                              <li class="regular">b</li>
                              <li class="regular">c</li>
                              <li class="regular">d</li>
                              <li class="regular">e</li>
                              <li class="regular">f</li>
                              <li class="regular">g</li>
                              <li class="regular">h</li>
                              <li class="regular">i</li>
                              <li class="regular">j</li>
                              <li class="regular">k</li>
                              <li class="regular">l</li>
                              <li class="regular">m</li>
                              <li class="regular">n</li>
                              <li class="regular">o</li>
                              <li class="regular">p</li>
                              <li class="regular">q</li>
                              <li class="premier">r</li>
                              <li class="premier">s</li>
                              <li class="premier">t</li>
                              <li class="premier">u</li>
                              <li class="premier">v</li>
                              <li class="premier">w</li>
                              <li>x</li>
                              <li>y</li>
                              <li>z</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>    
                    </div>

<div class="pink">I'm controlled by toggle. No JavaScript!</div>
<div class="black">I'm controlled by toggle. No JavaScript!</div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Im trying to switch the style when I click radio buttons. But im not able to select the id/class to target the radio:checked

Answer (score 1):

You can't select `.right-column` from the `input` because they aren't on the same DOM-level, neither on child nodes.
I simply move the checkboxes and remove the `.right-column` part of the selector:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .regular {
        color: pink;
      }
      #toggle-2[type='radio']:checked ~ .inner1 li.regular {
        background: gray;
        color: white;
      }
      #toggle-1[type='radio']:checked ~ .inner1 li.premier {
        background: red;
        color: lightgray;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrap">
      <div>I'm controlled by toggle. No JavaScript!</div>
      <div class="right-column">
        <input type="radio" id="toggle-1" name="radio" />
        <input type="radio" id="toggle-2" name="radio" />
        <div class="inner1">
          <div class="pink">this is a test</div>
          <ul>
            <li class="regular_m">a</li>
            <li class="regular">b</li>
            <li class="regular">c</li>
            <li class="regular">d</li>
            <li class="regular">e</li>
            <li class="regular">f</li>
            <li class="regular">g</li>
            <li class="regular">h</li>
            <li class="regular">i</li>
            <li class="regular">j</li>
            <li class="regular">k</li>
            <li class="regular">l</li>
            <li class="regular">m</li>
            <li class="regular">n</li>
            <li class="regular">o</li>
            <li class="regular">p</li>
            <li class="regular">q</li>
            <li class="premier">r</li>
            <li class="premier">s</li>
            <li class="premier">t</li>
            <li class="premier">u</li>
            <li class="premier">v</li>
            <li class="premier">w</li>
            <li>x</li>
            <li>y</li>
            <li>z</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="pink">I'm controlled by toggle. No JavaScript!</div>
      <div class="black">I'm controlled by toggle. No JavaScript!</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much - in that case how can I target if I need to have the code structured in this HTML

Comment: @user2680821 With CSS3, you cannot ascend on the DOM level, so you need to rework your HTML (or wait for CSS4 and pray for a parent selector). You can still use Javascript. This is quiet simple.